# Xcode 11.4.1 Not Responding

Tags: swift, xcode, macbookpro-touch-bar

every time Xcode Not Responding when i try to make some changes in code or in MainStoryboard or when i try to make new swift file, i always get this message "your system has run out of application memory"

[image]

This Is my Ram Without Xcode

[image]

Ram When i open Xcode
[image]

i have cleared all the cache, and derieved data also

this is my macbook info
[image]

Comment: I start thinking that 11.4.1 is another bad update after 11.3.1... no problem with 11.4

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be an Xcode software problem, the problem is not you. You can try to downgrade to 11.4 with this link : https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and by searching the 11.4 or previous xcode version.
If you don't want to downgrade, try to uninstall and then reinstall xcode or just wait for a new Xcode version which will probably correct this.